# Как загрузить файл с заданного URL и сохранить его в колонке типа BLOB?

Tags: sql, oracle, http, plsql, blob

Нужно создать процедуру, которая получит URL как параметр, загрузит файл с этого URL и сохранит его в колонке с типом BLOB.

Какой должен быть подход для достижения этой цели?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Procedure to download file from a given url in and save it into the blob type column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33706770) от участника [@Harshit Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4837155/harshit-gupta)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/33706770

Answer (score 3):

Самый простой способ, воспользоваться объектным типом [HTTPURITYPE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/Database-URI-TYPEs.html#GUID-653FBFE5-0477-41B0-8EDC-9EEFE40F8CB6):

> The HTTPURITYPE is a subtype of the UriType that provides support for the HTTP protocol. This uses the UTL_HTTP package underneath to access the HTTP URLs. **Proxy and secure wallets are not supported** in this release.

Обеспечивает поддержку протокола HTTP. Использует пакет `UTL_HTTP` для доступа к URL. **Прокси и безопасные кошельки не поддерживаются** в этом выпуске.

Простой пример:

```
create table urlres (url varchar2 (255), data blob, loaded date)
/
create or replace procedure loadbinary (url varchar2) as
    b blob;
begin
    b := httpuritype.createuri (url).getblob();
    insert into urlres values (url, b, sysdate);
end;
/
```

Запустить и результат:

```
exec loadbinary ('www.oracle.com/us/hp07-bgf3fafb-db12c-2421053.jpg');

select * from urlres
/
URL                              DATA             LOADED             
-------------------------------- ---------------- -------------------
www.oracle.com/us/hp07-bgf3fafb- FFD8FFE000104A46 2020-10-22 19:15:21
db12c-2421053.jpg                4946000101000001                    
                                 00010000FFDB0084                    
                                 0002020202020203                    
                                 0303030404030404
```

Comment: Дмитрий, то, что я вижу - синхронный запрос (к тому же без обработки ошибок). На сколько вообще этот подход (блокирующий) можно считать правильным? БД должна сама заниматься загрузкой файла? Как узнать, что загрузка не удачная и что-то предпринять?

Comment: @nörbörnën Это минимальный пример. Ошибки обрабатываются как обычно: `begin ... exceptions when ... then ... end;`, это `try ... catch ...`. Сами исключения надо смотреть в документации к конкретной ф-ии.

Comment: _БД должна сама заниматься загрузкой файла?_, не должна, но на этот вопрос трудно ответить однозначно. Кто-то решает, что так будет быстрей. Другие грузять их сначала внешним приложением в файловую систему, а потом батчем загружают в БД.

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться пакетом [UTL_HTTP](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/UTL_HTTP.html#GUID-A85D2D1F-90FC-45F1-967F-34368A23C9BB). Он поддерживает HTTPS (HTTP через SSL) и авторизацию. Для HTTPS потребуется создать кошелек с *Oracle Wallet Manager*.

Рабочий пример реализации:

```
create or replace procedure loadbinary (
    url varchar2, uname varchar2 := null, pass varchar2 := null, 
    walletpath varchar2 := null, walletpass varchar2 := null) as
    req  utl_http.req;
    resp utl_http.resp;
    bl blob;
    rw raw (32767);
begin
    if walletpath is not null and walletpass is not null then
        utl_http.set_wallet ('file:'||walletpath, walletpass);
    end if;

    req := utl_http.begin_request (url);
    if uname is not null and pass is not null then
        utl_http.set_authentication (req, uname, pass);
    end if;
    resp := utl_http.get_response (req);

    dbms_lob.createtemporary(bl, false);
    begin loop
        utl_http.read_raw (resp, rw, 32766);
        dbms_lob.writeappend (bl, utl_raw.length(rw), rw);
    end loop;
    exception when utl_http.end_of_body then
        utl_http.end_response (resp);
    end;
    insert into urlres values (url, bl, sysdate);

    dbms_lob.freetemporary (bl);
exception when others then
    utl_http.end_response (resp);
    dbms_lob.freetemporary (bl);
    raise;
end loadbinary;
/
```